# Using Parameterised Query to Populate Datalist

Tags: c#, sql, parameter-passing, datalist

I've been trying to pass a varying value in as sql query using parameters as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM Events 
WHERE EID NOT IN (SELECT TOP @limit EID FROM Events ORDER BY EID)
```

For finding the records after the first n rows specified by the value of the parameter `@limit`.

E.g. if I specify the value 10, then the query returns rows 6-10.

Right now what I'm doing is

```
string str = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Events WHERE EID NOT IN (SELECT TOP @limit EID FROM Events ORDER BY EID)"

SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(str,con); // con is the connection string

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("limit", value);

SqlDataAdapter sda= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);

return ds;
```

The dataset `ds` is then bound to a `Datalist`.

Currently an error is thrown saying

> "incorrect syntax near @limit"

What is (are) wrong with the code..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When pulling the `TOP n` using a parameter you have to enclose the parameter in parentheses:

```
string str= "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Events WHERE EID NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@limit) EID FROM Events ORDER BY EID)"
```